# Why does using spread synax(...) not honor type-safety for an expected return type in typescript

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax

I've got a function which is expected to return an object with specific keys. In my case, I only want to add the keys conditionally, so I am using spread syntax to help with that.

However, when I use spread syntax, I can add any old key to the object.
I would expect the TS compiler to be able to tell that this will add a property that shouldn't be allowed.

Is this a misunderstanding on my part of how things should work? A bug in TS compiler? A mistake in my code?

Removing the spread syntax around the `wut` property brings back the red squigglies I would expect to have there.

[TS-playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQOQDMD2OMA%20mARnAE6ElwBeGA3AFAMDGOAdgM7BQDmEw8ZBA5R0ACgCUALigAFcsACWiADwAlCKzIATFYJQAaKFzKK2PAHwXR1gN4MojqGX5IybKPafeouHDIwOHABbCAAxPAwDBx9HUmoAoNCAIRoomNiAOmyxWwB3JGBEkIgC4AwAXwkMqAqGCqA)

```
type Value = 'foo'| 'bar'| 'baz';

const getValues = (): Partial<Record<Value, string>> => {
    return {
        foo: 'someFoo',
        baz: 'someBaz',
        ...({wut: 'somewut'})
    }
}
```

Comment: _Excess property checks_ only apply in certain circumstances. The extra values aren't available via the interface anyway.

Comment: You're not doing destructuring. Here is a hint - the name is **de**structuring. It's because when you use it, you take *structured* data and pull it apart. Your code is not doing that - it's *constructing*. This is an object literal with [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) used for the last value. Spreading an object is essentially concatenation or enrichment of data. Both an object literal and spread are almost the opposite of destructuring.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @jonrsharpe. With the term "excess property checks", I was able to hunt down an open bug on typescript for this exact scenario.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39998

Comment: FYI: This is called not called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), but [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: ms/TS#39998 is not a bug but a feature request. Excess property checks aren’t a type safety feature but more of a linter feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the helpful comments, and apologies for the terminology mixup on my part re: destructuring/spread.

It looks like my options are to either forgo the type-safety and leave my code how it is, or add my properties directly within if statements to gate behind some conditional logic if I want to keep the type safety.

```
type Value = 'foo'| 'bar'| 'baz';

const getValues = (): Partial<Record<Value, string>> => {
    const result: Partial<Record<Value, string>> = {}
    if (true) { // assume something meaningful within the if()
        result.foo = 'someFoo'
    }
    if (true) { // assume something meaningful within the if()
        result.bar = 'someFoo'
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Terminology note: What you’re talking about isn’t *safety*. Types in typescript are allowed to have extra properties; otherwise you couldn’t extend interfaces or classes by adding properties.  Structural subtyping requires that a value has all the known properties but it does not require that it should *lack all unknown properties*.  It is “safe” to assign a value with extra properties to a type that doesn’t know about them. Prohibiting excess properties in the type system would require “exact types” which TS doesn’t have.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for the added context. 
This comment helped me realize that [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGICcCuBLWBeGBvAKBmJgDN0sAuGAcgEMAHBgGwFMaAaIkuVuqajQBGIOik4EAvgQKhIsRABUEDVgGU6pVqkwCYAJVagUAEwA8Ncrs4xoKDGADmAPhi5EOrAG4gA) would compile.
And it helped me understand why object spread can add extra properties.

I do still think that what I was referring to as safety does feel like safety though because it does ensure that the keys I'm returning in `getValues()` are indeed of type `Value`. But this was a very helpful comment. Thx

Comment: I meant that what you're talking about isn't type safety *with respect to TypeScript's type system*. If TypeScript had exact types (as requested in [ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)) and the type you were returning were (say) `Exact<Partial<Record<Value, string>>>`, then it would indeed be a safety issue to spread random stuff into it, since you'd be violating the contract of the type to do that.